# Trouble passing NetworkX node attributes to Bokeh ColumnDataSource in example

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, bokeh, networkx

## BLUF: Cannot pass node attributes from NetworkX to Bokeh in example - suspect the issue is that I'm not passing them to or within the function correctly.

Hello!

I'm having trouble translating NetworkX node attributes in to a CDS structure I can use in this example: https://gist.github.com/marquisthunder/ed690b132a7c655b4152bbcd7d84ed15

I have a feeling this should be relatively straightforward, but I'm quite new to python, networks, and stack overflow posting, and am really struggling with this. Please do let me know if/how I can demonstrate more question clarity.

I kick off my network here:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
import networkx as nx

with open('Desktop/Exports/Nodes_Master_0506.csv', 'r') as nodecsv: # Open the file                       
    nodereader = csv.reader(nodecsv) # Read the csv  
    # Retrieve the data (using Python list comprehension and list slicing to remove the header row)
    nodes = [n for n in nodereader][1:]                   

    #node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes]

with open('Desktop/Exports/Edges_Master_0428.csv', 'r') as edgecsv: # Open the file
    edgereader = csv.reader(edgecsv) # Read the csv     
    edges = [tuple(e) for e in edgereader] [1:] # Retrieve the data

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(list(G.nodes(data=True)))
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

I have had success adding attribute information to the hover tool outside of the example as a dictionary like this:

```
names_dict = {}
category_dict = {}
investor_dict = {}

for node in nodes: # Loop through the list, one row at a time
    names_dict[node[0]] = node[1]
    category_dict[node[0]] = node[3]
    investor_dict[node[0]] = node[7]

nx.set_node_attributes(G, names_dict, 'names')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, category_dict, 'category')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, investor_dict, 'investor')
```

The issue is that I cannot seem to retrieve these attributes *inside* the example. Outside of the example, then utilizing those attributes like `hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('category', '@category')` works just fine.

## I'm struggling to pass the attributes to the source_nodes in the example in the link above - I know that I somehow need to add the attributes to the ColumnDataSource component of source_nodes here.

```
source_nodes = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(dict(xs=_nodes.xs,
ys=_nodes.ys, name=_nodes.names, single_color = colors,
color_by_community = community_color_list, degree=degrees,
clustering=clustering, community_nr=community_nr, betweenness =
betw))

r_circles = fig.circle('xs', 'ys', fill_color='single_color',
line_color='single_color', source = source_nodes, alpha=0.7, 
size=9, name="show_hover")
```

I have searched similar questions, and have attempted to create a dict within the function like this: [How to pass node attributes from NetworkX to bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673098/how-to-pass-node-attributes-from-networkx-to-bokeh),

```
category_dict = []
category_dict = dict(zip(_nodes, category_dict))
nx.set_node_attributes(graph, {k:v for k,v in category_dict.items()},'category_dict' )
```

but when I pass those to source_nodes and run the function using my original graph built in the first code block, I get this error:

I've tried to be as succinct as possible with this given my newbie struggles, but please let me know if I can formulate this question better or provide more information!

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-4f4483870115> in <module>
----> 1 create_bokeh_graph(G)

<ipython-input-77-6d02981e5edc> in create_bokeh_graph(graph)
     78                                                       degree=degrees,
     79                                                       clustering=clustering, community_nr=community_nr,
---> 80                                                       betweenness = betw))
     81 
     82     r_circles = fig.circle('xs', 'ys', fill_color='single_color', line_color='single_color', 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/network/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/models/sources.py in __init__(self, *args, **kw)
    194                 raise ValueError("expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame, got %s" % raw_data)
    195         super().__init__(**kw)
--> 196         self.data.update(raw_data)
    197 
    198     @property

/opt/anaconda3/envs/network/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/property/wrappers.py in update(self, *args, **kwargs)
    376         for (owner, descriptor) in self._owners:
    377             hint = ColumnDataChangedEvent(owner.document, owner, cols=list(cols))
--> 378             descriptor._notify_mutated(owner, old, hint=hint)
    379 
    380         return result

/opt/anaconda3/envs/network/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/property/descriptors.py in _notify_mutated(self, obj, old, hint)
    865         # re-validate because the contents of 'old' have changed,
    866         # in some cases this could give us a new object for the value
--> 867         value = self.property.prepare_value(obj, self.name, value)
    868 
    869         self._real_set(obj, old, value, hint=hint)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/network/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/property/bases.py in prepare_value(self, obj_or_cls, name, value)
    329                     break
    330             else:
--> 331                 raise e
    332         else:
    333             value = self.transform(value)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/network/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/property/bases.py in prepare_value(self, obj_or_cls, name, value)
    322         try:
    323             if validation_on():
--> 324                 self.validate(value)
    325         except ValueError as e:
    326             for tp, converter in self.alternatives:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/network/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/property/container.py in validate(self, value, detail)
    183                     all(self.keys_type.is_valid(key) and self.values_type.is_valid(val) for key, val in value.items())):
    184                 msg = "" if not detail else "expected an element of %s, got %r" % (self, value)
--> 185                 raise ValueError(msg)
    186 
    187     @classmethod

ValueError: expected an element of ColumnData(String, Seq(Any)), got {'xs': (-0.4447982830708368, -0.34764264583629173........```
````

Comment: What does "cannot seem to retrieve these attributes inside the example" mean? In any case, every single value in the dict that you pass to `ColumnDataSource` must be a sequence like a list or array (with one thing in the lists for every node, in this case). The error is telling you that the dict you passed has a value that is not a sequence, and that is not something Bokeh can use.

Comment: Ah, yes - I think that's the part I can't quite grasp (sorry, all pretty new to me). I can't seem to translate the node attributes that I generate via the csv in the beginning (i.e. outside the function) in to a list/array within the example function necessary to feed ColumnDataSource. I can grasp the error but can't quite understand what syntax is necessary to utilize my attributes in the CDS.

Comment: @bigreddot oops, just realized I can add a tag!

Comment: What is the actual contents of your dict that you pass, currently?

Comment: @bigreddot once I set my node attributes:
i.e. `investor_dict = {}
for node in nodes: # Loop through the list, one row at a time
    investor_dict[node[0]] = node[7]
nx.set_node_attributes(G, investor_dict, 'investor_dict')`
I have something like this: `{'2': 'RRE Ventures', '3': 'StartX (Stanford-StartX Fund)', '6': 'Salesforce Ventures', '9': 'Citi Ventures'}`. 

I think that structure is wrong per your comment, but not quite sure how to fix.

Comment: @bigreddot Then, I try to utilize these attributes to tweak the function in the link by altering the HoverTool and source_nodes code in order to populate the node circles.

Perhaps I also need to create the attributes somewhere within the example function - rather than referencing it beforehand?